# SystemJs, Angular2 importing files

Tags: angular, systemjs

this is my systemJs config in index.html

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });

  System.import('./ts/app.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

app.js

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {loginDirective} from './login-directive.js';

@Component({
selector: 'loginForm',
directives: [loginDirective],
templateUrl:'./view/login_view.html'
})

export class loginForm{

};

bootstrap(loginForm);
```

Why I have always define .js in import (login-directive.js) or in system js app.js, not just login-directive and app if defaultExtension is set to "js"?

tnx
miha

Comment: I believe that defaultExtension is being deprecated but left in for backwards compatibility. It fights with the way plugin loaders work, and breaks loading things from cdns that host without extensions.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, with your SystemJS configuration, `format = 'register'` and `defaultExtension = 'js'` only apply to module that starts with app/.

```
System.import('app/boot')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

or if the `component.js` is located is located under the `app` folder (I consider here that the import is done within a module under `app`, for example the `app/boot` module):

```
import { ... } from './component';
```

Here is the structure:

```
app/
  boot.js (compiled from boot.ts)
  component.js (compiled from component.ts)
```

Otherwise SystemJS will try to load module directly with their names

```
System.import('ts/app.js')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: hi thierry, this is default behaviour by systemJS? How should i change my config that this will work (ts/)?

Comment: I would put `ts` into your SystemJS configuration instead of `app` in the `packages` block but be careful: app.js can contain TypeScript file if you use transpiling on the fly with SystemJS:  `System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, ...`

Comment: hi:) tnx for this...

I would be really grateful for one little small help regarding this.

ok, I my SystemJs config looks like this:

System.config({ app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' } });

  System.import('app/boot.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
but in app folder i still have do import like this:

import { gsHeader } from "../app/components/app.gsheader.js";
what I could be doing wrong? now I am in app folder.

tnxMiha